# Add own application icon to QuickAction Dialog after contact icon click

Tags: android, dialog

I want to add my own application icon to QucikAction Dialog in Contacts[image] in Android.
I found this http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

I have application which using contacts (People) and I want go to the desirable contact (by stack appliction managing contacts), click on contact's icon and QuickAction Dialog should contain icon of my app, I clicked and my app shoud start with contact info.

How to do it?

Comment: Link you found gives very clear explaination,where is the problem exactly??

Comment: The link shows how to create your own quick Action dialog. I think you need to check SampleSyncAdapter in sample application

Comment: Link gives very clear explanation how to make QuickAction dialog, but I want to add icon of my app to QucikAction dialog of **stack application to manage Contacts**

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** do this, this is not supported by stock "Phone" or "Contacts" apps.

A reason behind this - list of quick actions shows possible **type** of **actions** that you can do with underlying contact, rather than **list** of **apps** that can do *something* with this contact.

All you can do is add your app to list of some predefined actions, like "sending SMS", "making a phone call", "viewing photos", etc. In order to do this you need to specify correct intent-filters in your manifest file. In that case your app can appear in list of apps that shows after user clicks one of quick actions mentioned above

Comment: I tried add to manifest "sending SMS" etc and still doesn't work. Have you ever seen working example with this problem? I search in google but I haven't found enything yet..

Comment: I think I answer your initial question (please consider accepting/upvoting it). Regarding your new question - yes, I have working code samples, but I think it will be better to post separate question, when I will be able to post some code samples and make a good answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383692/predefined-actions-of-application-link-to-my-application-from-contacts